# How to automatically virtually boot partition windows 11 inside from windows server 2022 through VM or VMware or hyper-V?

Tags: virtual-machines, hyper-v, windows-server-2016, vmware-workstation, thin-client

**Question : How to automatically virtually boot partition  windows 11  inside from windows server 2019 through VM or VMware?**

In my  small coaching institue computer lab with  25pc. 15 pc are Independet desktops and  10 are thin client ncomputing diskless CPU less.

i had made I7 server machine have installed Multi booting with three windows OS in three different patritions ie. (C drive) windows server 2022 evaluation & (D drive) windows 11 evaluation  &  (E Drive) windows 10 evaluation and fully installed with programming and multimedia application for teaching purposes.

I  am running  Domain controller in windows server 2022 with roaming profiles of other independent 15 pc. Now i want to run think client  Ncomputing server on the same i7 sever machine on windows server or windows 11/10.

As for centralising users privalages restrictions through group policies  i had configured windows server  2022 through roaming  profiles of  independent 15 pc .

Now company thin client i am using is not supporting domain controller  or  server 2022 on server side its compatible with  windows 10 or windows 11 sever and client side.

what i am planning firstly to boot from C drive windows server 2022 evaluation version through group policy and romaing folder redirections configured. Secondly i want to boot paralley within inside windows server 2022 i want to boot windows 11  installed and configure for thinclient server.

I dont know if it is possible, I want to parallely boot windows 11 parition (d drive) or bootbale image file (img)  with thin client ncomputing installed within from windows server 2022 through virtual machine or VMWare application .

Is it possible to boot another windows partition installed window  and both  windows server and windows 11 run parallely together from same pc and windows 11 boot automatically boot daily from inside  windows server 2019.

if not then can we configure setup VM  or vmware  for windows 11 with ncomputing thin client and  save and run daily and  make  run all  ncomputing think client  machines from windows 11.

i hope  u understand i want windows server 2022 and windows 11 to run paralley from same machine.

Kindly need some expert advice  for the same problem.  it will be helpful if some one can share  some step by step process  links or videos  to how to do the same as  i am NOVICE for vmware and virtual box or hyper v

Comment: It's very hard to understand the question, due to some typos (maybe) and general understanding of the problem. You want to *boot* some OSses from the same hardware in parallel, without virtualization?

Comment: @bjoster bro yes, i want to to boot already installed windows 11 in second primary  partition (d drive) of same machine from (inside) windows server 2019 mainly booted (from C drive main first active primary partition) parallerly..through hyperv or vmware or virtual box  or any other method u may tell

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is possible with basically any hypervisor (virtualization software). Since you are running Windows Server already you could simply install the hyper-v role on that server and set up a new VM that uses your drive D as a disk. That should work in most scenarios though keep in mind that for your Windows 11 machine it will look like it is booting in another PC with different hardware, so it will have to reinstall some drivers etc. In most cases this should work fine but there is a potential for problems to arise. To be on the safe side, you could instead set up a fresh VM, install it with the operating system you need / want and then migrate your workload from your current Windows 11 Installation over into your new VM.
The VM can then be configured to automatically start / resume when the Guest OS (in this case your Windows Server) starts up.

Comment: @ MoWo thanks a lotz  for hyper V role i will study it ...any link you can suggest for  the same

Comment: @Androidquery well there are lots and lots of good resources about working with hyper-v. Maybe as a start you could check this article that guides you through the first steps: https://techgenix.com/beginners-guide-to-hyper-v-revisited/
But I'd encourage you to just google whatever specific question you have and you're very likely to quickly find an answer...

Comment: thanx a lot again for sharing the link.. yes i could find the links for frehsly install on hyper or vmware...but while googling i cant find to load an existing installed d drive parition on VMware ,Vmbox or hyper-v ..can u how to virtually boot the  d drive installed parition through hyper v

Comment: @Androidquery you could try the approach mentioned here: https://www.informaticar.net/how-to-attach-physical-disk-to-vm-inside-hyper-v/
But be aware that booting directly from your drive will modify that installation and may make it unbootable in your main pc afterwards. If you don't want to risk that, another approach would be to create a new virtual disk and clone the contents of the physical drive into it. See instructions here: https://www.veeam.com/blog/how-to-convert-physical-machine-hyper-v-virtual-machine-disk2vhd.html
This way you get a copy of your disk and can experiment safely.